# Error creating pod on master node: Error failed to get sandbox container task: no task found

Tags: kubernetes, raspberry-pi, k3s

Very new to K3s and I'm attempting to just practice by creating a deployment with 3 replicas of an ngnix pod. It creates on 2 of my worker nodes but one of the pods tried creating on my master node but I got a CreateContainerError.
After digging further I found the following error: Error: failed to get sandbox container task: no running task found: task e2829c0383965aa4556c9eecf1ed72feb145211d23f714bdc0962b188572f849 not found: not found.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

After running `kubectl describe node` and checking the taints for the master node, it shows `<none>`

Comment: Hello @BretBeatty and welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please run `kubectl describe node` command and check the taints that your master node has? Please edit your question with the proper outputs.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I ran the command and edited my question with the output.

Answer (score 1):

So all it needed was a fresh install and that seems to have solved everything. Probably should have tried that first.